# Deal with interfaces ans structures

Tags: typescript

I want to deal with user roles in my app. I want to use my code something like that:

```
export interface User{
 name: string
 roles: Roles[]
}
interface Roles{
  ADMIN: new Permissions(1,1,1,1,1),
  MOD: new Permissions(1,0,1,1,0,0),
 [...]
}

const user:User = {
 name:"Me",
 roles:[
  Roles.ADMIN
]
}
```

I hope you understand what i would like to achive, Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Think of interfaces as compile time object template. It is not designed to do what an enum does.

```js
enum Roles {
  ADMIN = 1 >> 0,
  MOD = 1 >> 1,
  // ...
}
```

And everything should be the same